# What Bulk / Transactional Email Delivery Service do you use with CiviCRM? What is your experience like?

Tags: civimail, email, mailing, mailserver, inbound-email

I know this isn't a typical stackexchange question - but where else would we have a discussion like this?

Our journey with email delivery via CiviCRM has been interesting. First we were sending email blasts using our self hosted email server. Deliverability was good, but we often ended up in spam folders. Then we started using Sparkpost from Messagebird - overall it was a better experience but recently people have been reporting that they never get any emails - not even spam - which tells us that their email providers might be totally blocking our emails or our provider's IPs.

Providers like Mailchimp, etc are so successful because they work hard to make sure their emails get through to everyone. CiviCRM has a number of plugins for email providers - which ones do you use? How has your experience been? Here are a few that I found:

- [Amazon Simple Email Service](https://civicrm.org/extensions/amazon-simple-email-service-ses)
- [Sparkpost](https://civicrm.org/extensions/sparkpost),  [Alternative Sparkpost](https://civicrm.org/extensions/sparkpost-symbiotic) (Most popular from what I see)
- [SendGrid](https://civicrm.org/extensions/sendgrid-event-notification-processor)
- [Mandrill](https://civicrm.org/extensions/mandrill-simple), [Alternative Mandrill](https://civicrm.org/extensions/mandrill-email) (Mailchimp Transactional)
- [AirMail](https://civicrm.org/extensions/airmail) (supports Amazon SES, Elastic Email and Sendgrid)
- [MailGun](https://civicrm.org/extensions/mailgunny)

There are other providers too, like PostMark & Brevo (used to be sendinblue), but as far as I know, Civi does not have support for them.

Answer (score 2):

We use AWS SES without issues. Setup is straigtforward. Deliverability is excellent. Costs are covered by their $1000/pa for non-profits. No complaints there.

Answer (score 1):

We use AWS SES as well, with a dedicated IP address, also for free with non-profit credits. Can't complain. AWS will send emails faster than CiviCRM can.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [postmarkapp.com SMTP service](https://postmarkapp.com/smtp). They do transactional emails, but they also have a broadcast stream for this kind of thing. They're well known for being easy to set up, and they're deliverability tends to be better than these others.

Comment: How do you track bounces?

Comment: Trev - are you working for that company - if so then I think you should be clearer about that, eg rather than using the term 'they' you use the term 'we'.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Mailjet](https://mailjet.com) for some of my client, which is brilliant at delivery.  There's also an extension called [Mailjetty](https://civicrm.org/extensions/mailjetty-bounce-handler-mailjet) which reports bounces back in Civi.  You can test for free too, which is good.